# Understanding Kendrick's reference to Tetris in "Humble"

Tags: song-lyrics, kendrick-lamar

In Kendrick Lamar's new single "Humble", he references the game Tetris:

> Pull up on your block, then break it down: we playin' Tetris
>   A.M. to the P.M., P.M. to the A.M., funk

I'm not quite sure what the reference to Tetris is supposed to mean. I've seen several different interpretations of that line online, and I'm curious to get everyone's thoughts.

Comment: "*Pull up on your block, then break it down*" sounds quite a bit like Tetris. How well does that part of the line fit into the wider context of the song?